# Use implicit differentiation to find an equation of the tangent line to the curve at the given point $(2,4)$

Tags: derivatives, implicit-differentiation

Find an equation of the tangent line to the curve at the given point $(2,4)$

$$x^2+2xy-y^2+x=6$$

I got a derivative of $\frac{-2y-1-2x}{2(y-x)}$ and a slope of $-3.25$ and $y=10.5-3.25x$ as my equation of the tangent line. However, this turned out to be incorrect and I can't figure what I've done wrong.

Comment: I do get a different derivative than yours. Note $xy$ is a product, use product rule, and for $y^2$ chain rule too. Start with $2x+2y+2xy'-2yy'+1=0$, etc.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a sign error. The correct implicit derivative is

$$\frac{2y+2x+1}{2(y-x)}$$

which gives in $(2,4)$ a slope of $\frac{13}{4}=+3.25$ and a tangent line

$$y=\frac{13}{4}x-\frac{5}{2}$$

Comment: Yep,  you're right. Thanks a bunch.